# Why setting xdebug.max_nesting_level=200 not getting picked up from php.ini file?

Tags: php, xdebug, vagrantfile

I have a vagrantfile I am using to bring up a box Ubuntu box and I've defined php provisioning like this :

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get -y install php5 php5-dev php5-curl php5-imagick php5-gd php5-mcrypt php5-mhash php5-mysql php5-xdebug php5-intl php5-xsl"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo php5enmod mcrypt"
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo \"xdebug.max_nesting_level=200\" >> /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini" 
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "sudo apt-get -y install phpunit"
```

I can also see that this really does update the php.ini file on the box that's created.
[image: cat php.ini output]
Whith all this set I don't understand why I still get this error :

```
==> default: PHP Fatal error:  Maximum function nesting level of '100' reached, aborting! in /vagrant-B05032-Magento-Box/vendor/magento/framework/Code/Reader/ClassReader.php on line 59
==> default: PHP Stack trace:
==> default: PHP   1. {main}() /vagrant-B05032-Magento-Box/bin/magento:0
==> default: PHP   2. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /vagrant-B05032-Magento-Box/bin/magento:25
==> default: PHP   3. Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() /vagrant-B05032-Magento-Box/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
```

Any thoughts what could be wrong here ?

Comment: Does it work after restarting the box? Thinking apache isn't restarted after the ini file is updated

Comment: Is there another php.ini file somewhere?      I had issues with php.ini and discovered that xdebug was actually using the cli version which was in a different directory.

Comment: @JimL : Tried rebooting and starting, still the same thing. In the Vagrant file, I have Apache provisioning after this php update. So that should by default take care of having the last file available right ?

Comment: @Mark_1 Couldn't find it anywhere else, do you remember the directory you found that file ?

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to figure this out. I needed to add the max_nesting_level to these two files as well.

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo \"xdebug.max_nesting_level=1000\" >> /etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini" 
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: "echo \"xdebug.max_nesting_level=1000\" >> /etc/php5/mods-available/xdebug.ini"
```

I am sure that in the end one of these parameters is actually used not sure which one. Maybe I'll make the change to Vagrantfile and test it one by one. But for now the problem is solved... :)